# output comes out to an integer when I want a string

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionTwo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer number;
        Character first, middle, last;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        first = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Middle name: ");
        middle = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        last = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Which type of sort order would you like (1 for ascending and 2 for descending)? ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (number == 1) {

            System.out.println("Sort order: 1");

            if ((first) < (middle) && (first) < (last)) {

                if ((middle) < (last)) {

                    System.out.println(first + middle + last);
                }

                if ((last) < (middle)) {
                    System.out.println(first + last + middle);
                }
            }

            if ((middle) < (first) && (middle) < (last)) {

                if ((first) < (last)) {
                    System.out.println(middle + first + last);
                }
                if ((last) < (first)) {

                    System.out.println(middle + last + first);
                }
            }

            if ((last) < (middle) && (last) < (first)) {

                if ((middle) < (first)) {
                    System.out.println(last + middle + first);
                }
                if ((first) < (middle)) {
                    System.out.println(last + first + middle);
                }
            }
        }

        if (number == 2) {
            System.out.println("Sort order: 2");
            if ((first) > (middle) && (first) > (last)) {
                if ((middle) > (last)) {
                    System.out.println(first + middle + last);
                }

                if ((last) > (middle)) {
                    System.out.println(first + last + middle);
                }
            }

            if ((middle) > (first) && (middle) > (last)) {
                if ((first) > (last)) {
                    System.out.println(middle + first + last);
                }

                if ((last) > (first)) {
                    System.out.println(middle + last + first);
                }
            }

            if ((last) > (middle) && (last) > (first)) {
                if ((middle) > (first)) {
                    System.out.println(last + middle + first);
                }

                if ((first) > (middle)) {
                    System.out.println(last + first + middle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output that I get from this is a large integer value, whereas what the program should do is ask for a first name, then middle name, then last name. It should then ask for which sort order, 1 being ascending and 2 being descending. What this means is that once it gets the name it looks through the names and counts the number of letters per name. It will then give the answer as the name sorted in the order that the user selected.

For example:

if I tell it my name is David H. Anderson, and click 1 for ascending order, my result should be "H. David Anderson", as H. is 2 symbols, David is 5 and Anderson is 8.

What it currently does is all of the above except for giving me the last line int he format I want (I end up just getting a number).

Comment: why are you trying to get only the first char of the expected inputs ?

Comment: Please format your code properly, including removing superfluous newlines.

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I suggest you to read about the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @mustabelMo. Not just that, but OP is storing the numerical value of those characters instead of the characters as a string.

Comment: What's the purpose of `.charAt(0)`? That's what is causing your issue.

Comment: One thing that should be quite obvious: you're reading the names but you're not storing them. Example: `first = keyboard.next().charAt(0);`, here you get the first name but only store the first character of that name.

Comment: @OP. You failed to read the docs about the methods you are using. Your program works as coded.

Comment: And have you heard about the [if-then-else statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)?

Comment: What Mad Physicist meant is that `last + first + middle` will _not_ concatenate the characters but instead convert them to numbers and add those. Use `String` instead of `Character`, along with `compareTo()` for comparisons (or, if I understand your question correctly, compare the `length()` of your variables) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionTwo

{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Integer number;

    String first, middle, last;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("First name: ");

    first = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Middle name: ");

    middle = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Last name: ");

    last = keyboard.next();

    System.out.print("Which type of sort order would you like (1 for ascending and 2 for descending)? ");

    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    int firstLength = first.length();
    int middleLength = middle.length();
    int lastLength = last.length();

    if(number == 1)
    {
      System.out.println("Sort order: 1");

  if(firstLength < middleLength && firstLength < lastLength)
  {

    if(middleLength < lastLength)
    {

      System.out.println (first + " " + middle + " " + last);
    }

    if(lastLength < middleLength)
    {

      System.out.println (first + " " + last + " " + middle);
   }
  }

  if(middleLength < firstLength && middleLength < lastLength)
  {

    if(firstLength < lastLength)
    {

      System.out.println (middle + " " + first + " " + last);
    }

    if(lastLength < firstLength)
    {

      System.out.println (middle + " " + last + " " + first);
    }
  }

  if(lastLength < middleLength && lastLength < firstLength)
  {

    if(middleLength < firstLength)
    {

      System.out.println(last + " " + middle + " " + first);
    }

    if(firstLength < middleLength)
   {

     System.out.println(last + " " + first + " " + middle);
    }
  }
}

if(number == 2)
{

  System.out.println("Sort order: 2");

   if(firstLength > middleLength && firstLength > lastLength)
  {

    if(middleLength > lastLength)
    {

      System.out.println (first + " " + middle + " " + last);
    }

    if(lastLength > middleLength)
    {

      System.out.println (first + " " + last + " " + middle);
    }
  }

  if(middleLength > firstLength && middleLength > lastLength)
  {

    if(firstLength > lastLength)
    {

     System.out.println (middle + " " + first + " " + last);
    }

    if(lastLength > firstLength)
    {

      System.out.println (middle + " " + last + " " + first);
    }
  }

  if(lastLength > middleLength && lastLength > firstLength)
 {

    if(middleLength > firstLength)
    {

      System.out.println(last + " " + middle + " " + first);
    }

    if(firstLength > middleLength)
    {

      System.out.println(last + " " + first + " " + middle);
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Listening to the comments and with help from thanopi57, I was able to get the proper answer. The first thing I did was to remove the ".AtChar(0)" and define the variables as Strings, not Characters. I then defined the variables as variable length, with variable xxxx becoming int xxxxLength=xxxx.Length();, doing this for all three variables (which converted them from String to Int). I then replaced the subsequent concatenation operands with my newly defined variables, I also added " " for spaces inbetween operands in the println lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would change a few things to get you started.

Firstly, your input should probably be a `String`

Secondly, remove `.charAt(0)`

Then compare the `String` lengths before printing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main2 {

    private static ArrayList<String> splitAndSortFullName(String fullName, int sortOrder) {
        String[] names = fullName.split(" "); //Split names by space character.

        //Create a list with only non-empty names:
        ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i=0; i<names.length; ++i)
            if (!names[i].isEmpty())
                namesList.add(names[i]);

        switch (sortOrder) {
            case 1: Collections.sort(namesList); break;
            case 2: Collections.sort(namesList, (a, b) -> { return b.compareTo(a); }); break;
        }

        return namesList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter full name: ");

        String fullName = keyboard.nextLine(); //Read the full name. For example "John D. Doe".

        System.out.print("Which type of sort order would you like (1 for ascending and 2 for descending)? ");

        int number = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(splitAndSortFullName(fullName, number));

        //For use with many full names, just re-call the method splitAndSortFullName(...). For examples:
        System.out.println("Full examples:");
        System.out.println(splitAndSortFullName("John D. Doe", 1));
        System.out.println(splitAndSortFullName("Alice K. Example", 2));
        System.out.println(splitAndSortFullName("Martin T. Anderson", 1));
    }
}
```

In this code, the user enters his complete name fully.

Comment: how would I make it so that this program sorts with separate inputs, because it does what I want, just not exactly

Comment: What do you mean "separate inputs"? Can you update your question? Do you want this answer to be converted into a single method for example?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase: How would I write the program so that it takes in 3 separate names and displays the answer as your program does (I'm currently working on fixing issues in mine, but help would be nice)

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, you can call the method `splitAndSortFullName` any number of times you want.

Comment: not what I wanted, but extremely helpful, I've been using your code to help fix my own and so far it's working, I'll end up posting the exact answer to my question myself at this rate- all thanks to you.